# Не получается отправить файл на сервер, если соединение длится больше 30 секунд

Tags: php, сеть, request, fileupload

При длительной загрузки файла на сервер (более 30 секунд) теряется сигнал, при этом нет ответа от сервера. Запрос просто весит в Панели разработчика. Размер файла не важен. Чем быстрее интернет, тем больше файл загрузит. Я пробовал увеличить `max_execution_time`. Это не дало своих плодов. За любую подсказку\помощь буду благодарен

Сервер работает на: `FastCGI (Apache)`

В логах последняя строка:

```
2021/10/05 10:58:23 [warn] 6912#6912: *239411990 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /tmp/nginx_body_temp/0009878789, request: "POST /rest/file/create HTTP/1.1"
```

[image: Панель разработчика]

Comment: логи веб-сервера смотреть. актуальное значение max_execution_time проверять

Comment: @Ипатьев, добавил, все остальные сообщения, выглядят нормально

Comment: и до какого значения ты увеличил? если теперь загрузить еще больший файл, то обрывается аналогично на этом большем значении?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, до 300. Разницы нет. http://migrationrus.ru/phpinfo.php, тут можете посмотреть. Возможно что-то настроено не верно

Comment: какой конкретно разницы нет? так обрывается теперь на 30 или 300?

Comment: Я бы в пхп скрипте поставил отладочное логирование. чтобы понять, доходит ли до него вообще дело, или нет. ну и внимательнее смотрел логи. если происходит обрыв соединения, то это должно быть отражено.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, без изменений, 30 секунд и теряется сигнал. Если файл успевает загрузить в течении 30 секунд, то сервер отдает статус 200

Comment: @Ипатьев, только это

Comment: если в пхп стоит отладочное логирование, которое видно в логах при нормальной загрузке, и которого нет при задержках, то до пхп дело не доходит. и следовательно, вопрос вообще не сюда.